# How to convolve $u(n)$ and $u(-n-5)$ without using $z$ transform

Tags: convolution, z-transform

As the title says, I wanted to test the property of the $z$ transform where:

$$z[x(n) \cdot x(h)] = z[x(n)] z [h(n)].$$

I have already solved the right hand part. All that remains to show is the left part, which I don't know how to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you meant to type $u[n-5]$ rather than $u[-n-5]$ since the convolution that you have provided results in a non-convergent sum.

We compute
$$
(x_1 * x_2)[n] = u[n-5] * u[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty u[k-5]u[n-k]
$$
Note that each product being added comes out to either $1$ or $0$.

Now, for a fixed $n$, we note that $n - k \geq 0$ means that $k \leq n$.  On the other hand, $k -5 \geq 0$ means that $k \geq 5$.  Thus, for any $n$, $(x_1*x_2)[n]$ is the number of integers $k$ that satisfy both $k \geq 5$ and $k \leq n$.  That is, we have
$$
(x_1 *x_2)[n] = \begin{cases}
0 & n < 5\\
(n-4) & n \geq 5
\end{cases} = (n-4)\cdot u[n-4]
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But the given is correct, It is what the professor gave us. Assuming that my professor did that intentionally how do i show that it is a non convergent sum?

Comment: For any $k \leq \min\{-5,n\}$, we have $u[k-5]u[-n-k] = 1$.  So, the sum $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty u[k-5]u[-n-k]$ diverges to infinity for any value of $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 